# Ajax post response coming back successfully - can't log/print to screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm successfully posting data to the server via $.post(). When I attempt to do anything with the response, I get nothing. No console log. Can't replace text or HTML with the data. Nothing.

Here's the post:

```
$.post(myUrl, {myVar: myVar}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And here's the response:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be able to "guess" the data type as the default 4th parameter not set implies. [set dataType parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$.post(myUrl, {myVar: myVar}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, 'text');
```

Also be sure that it returns a `200 OK` response from the server or else success won't run.

Comment: Huh, adding the dataType worked! I've done a lot of ajax posts and have never had to set the 4th param for simple text. Any idea why I'd need to do that? In this case, I'm passing a moment through, but I'm formatting it prior to sending, so typeof is string - target.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'). 2 mins until I can accept as answer :)

Comment: It might be the response header's `content-type`. What is your returning?

Comment: It's coming back "application/json".

Comment: Thats the issue then you are not returning valid `json` and the jquery is looking at the content header to determine the converter to use.  Look at `jquery.parseJSON` http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js you will see it uses `JSON.parse( data + "" )` you can see that by looking at the values of `accepts:` and `converters` in `ajaxSettings:`

Comment: Why does it default to json? In that case I wasn't using json_encode($result). I was just echoing $_POST['myVar']

Comment: We would have to see your server side code to know the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the response (probably) into a `JSON` format so that you can catch it. PHP's header for JSON is:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json"); //Set header for outputing the JSON information
```

You will need to include that in your PHP file that you are sending a request to. You may also need to specify the headers content in the `post` request, as I mainly use `Angular`, I'm a bit unsure of what the `AJAX` header for this case, but try something like:

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
```